# Rails : file upload using paperclip plugin - changing the default location where files are stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

Hi Id like to change the default location that paperclip saves its files to .
From the documentation I see that the default location is at

```
rails_root/public/system/users/images/.....
```

Id like to save the files to

```
rails_root/assets/images/uploads/.....
```

So I changed the User model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :image , :url => ":rails_root/assets/images/uploads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                           :path => ":rails_root/assets/images/uploads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension" 

end
```

However, this did not work. When I upload the file and go to the "show" page I see the following screen.

[image]

As you can see the user is created however. The image link is broken and when I click on the link 
I get this message on the web page

```
No route matches [GET] "/Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/bmc_mam/assets/images/uploads/13/original/bmc_TransparentFinal.png"
```

Can someone please help me understand this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images won't be served directly from `assets` without you having to do some configuration. They would need to be at `Rails.root/public/assets/images/uploads/etc.` to be seen via browser. In a browser, the path to the image would be something like `http://foo.com/assets/images/uploads/etc.`. `public` will be stripped off by default. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application for some information on the default directory structure of a Rails app.